# Responsive form not editable on mobile

Tags: html, css, forms, mobile, responsive-design

I'm newer to editing responsive landing pages and cannot figure out why this form cannot be filled in on mobile. The form works on larger screens. Is anyone able to help? Much appreciated!

Landing page: https://pages.ciphercloud.com/lp-test-4.html

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It's best you post the HTML/CSS/JS in your question since that link you provided will soon disappear and no one will be able to learn from your question or even know what you were asking.

Answer (score 0):

put your form col in a row:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-sm-pad-left pad-top test">
        ....
        ....
    </div>
</div>
```